# Jquery Popup/Modal-Box with Forwarding (and Event?)

Tags: ajax, jquery, popup, modal-dialog

i hope anybody can help me ...

index.php (http://jsbin.com/elocek)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.open').popupWindow({ 
    windowURL:'popup.php', 
    windowName:'external' 
    });
 });
</script>
```

popup.php (http://jsbin.com/agepog)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('.close').click(function() {
        window.close();
    });

    });
</script>
```

so you can see 2 files, the "index.php" is only a snippet from the whole one but you can see the jquery etc. my problem is i would open a popup/modal-box whatever - see the new window and would like to reload/refresh/replace the mainwindow (index.php) if i close the popup/modal-box ... is this possible?

the index.php has some additional vars e.q. index.php?site=news&text=....

**(sorry for my bad english)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('.close').click(function() {
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
    });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks Shankar ... "window.opener.location.reload(true);" works or better "window.opener.location.reload();" is it also possible to forward to an other url?

Comment: Passing true will try to avoid the form post confirmation in most of the browsers. You can just say reload() it will work since in your case I guess the request type is get. To open a new url just set the new url to `window.opener.location.href`